# Is there a way to use on-do actions to remove the In Condition before rerunning a Control-M job in version 9?

Tags: control-m

I've got a problem on BMC CtrlM V.9, i want a job who delete a In Condition before perform a rerun, to be in a state that it waits again his in condition.

I tried to use the on-do actions in this way:
On Job ended OK
DO remove the condition
DO rerun.

But it keeps rerun before removing the condition and then start immediatly while i want it to be in a awaiting state.
Can someone see whats going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That should work, are you removing the condition by using the delete tick on the input conditions panel?

Maybe best if you just post a screenshot of the post-processing panel.